# Query is very slow when we put a where clause on the total selected data by query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query which is selecting data on the basis of joins between 6-7 tables. When I execute the query it is taking 3-4 seconds to complete. But when I put a `where` clause on the fetched data it's taking more than one minute to execute. My query is fetching large amounts of data so I can't write it here but the situation I faced is explained below:

```
Select Category,x,y,z
from 
(
---Sample Query
) as a
```

it's only taking 3-4 seconds to execute. But

```
Select Category,x,y,z
from 
(
---Sample Query
) as a
where category Like 'Spart%'
```

is taking more than 2-3 minutes to execute.

Why is it taking more time to execute when I use the `where` clause?

Comment: At a guess, lack of a suitable index to perform a seek on `category`, thus a full table scan is performed. Consider posting your two execution plans and sharing them using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), or at least posting your DDL (including Indexes).

Comment: Also, the subquery is going to be needed here. Without that, everything will be guess work, as we have no idea what `category` really is (for example, is it derived in the subquery? Do you perform `CAST` or `CONVERT` on the value?)

Comment: Where are you runing this? Are you sure it's returning quicker? It might be returning the first row quicker but it's probably still running

Comment: I can't share the query but we have indexing on our all tables except one table. No CAST/CONVERT is performed. data for Category coming from a transaction table which is mapped with a master table on the basis of category code and master table returning the name of Category. not any type of subquery@Larnu

Comment: Not necessarily, @Nick.McDermaid. it could well be the `WHERE` is increasing execution time. Consider a (very) simple query like : `SELECT A, B FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable);`. Consider that `MyTable` has a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on `A` and an `INDEX` on `B`. This should be a pretty quick query, even if the table contains 100M> rows and 50+ columns (as the other 48 aren't considered). Now, let's change it to: `SELECT A, B FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable) WHERE C LIKE 'Car%';`. There is no `INDEX` on `C`. This would likely perform poorly, as the value of `C` needs to be checked on **every** row.

Comment: I am running this on SSMS. i am getting message that query executed completely and time of execution is 4 Sec. but when where clause comes in the time is 2-3 Minutes.

Comment: Indexing on "all your tables"? That doesn't make sense. You don't "index your table" you index the columns in a table. If you can't share the query qith us, the execution plans, the DDL or the indexes, we **can't** help you. Much like a garage would tell you they can't fix your car if you won't let them look at it.

Comment: You already said that in the original post. You received multiple comments that could address your issue and you are ignoring them. Doubt you will get an answer at this rate...

Comment: Are the statistics of this table recently updated ? Do you have a job or something that keeps all table and index statistics up to date ?

Comment: 3 to 4 seconds is a long time for any query. Howmany records do the tables contain ? Does SSMS advices you to add an index ? Are your statistics uptodate ? There could be many things playing here

Comment: I assume that `Category` is a `GROUP BY` field in the subquery ? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, Category is a Group by field in Subquery@patrick. 

Statistics are up to date and SSMS advised to create a Index but i cant create any DDL commands on Database.@GuidoG

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say exactly what the issue is without seeing the full query. It is likely that the optimiser is pushing the WHERE into the "Sample query" in a way that is not performant. Possibly could be resolved by updating statistics on the table, but an easier option would be to insert the whole query into a temporary table, and filter from there.

```
Select Category,x,y,z
INTO #temp
from 
(
---Sample Query
) as a

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE category Like 'Spart%'
```

This will force the optimiser to tackle it in the logical order of pulling your data together before applying the WHERE to the end result. You might like to consider indexing the temp table's category field also.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS SQL by checking the management studio actual execution plan it may already suggest an index creation

In any case, you should add to the index used by the query the column "Category"

If you don't have an index on that table create it composed by column "Category" and all the other columns used in join or where

bear in mind by using like 'text%' clause you could end in index scan and not index seek